# Rails s3_direct_upload without file field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

My website generates a file in javascript (audio recording) and I then want it to be uploaded to Amazon S3.

I first managed to get the uploading part working by sending the generated file to my server, where it is uploaded. However I would like now to upload the file directly to S3, without going through my server.

So I started to use the s3_direct_upload gem, which works great when using a file_field. However my file is generated by the javascript and :
- The value of a file field has to be set by the user for security reasons
- I do not want the user to have to interact with the upload

I tried to play with the S3Uploader class and to directly add data, without any success for now, it seems that I do not use the correct method.
Does anyone has any idea on how to achieve S3 direct upload without a file field ?

Thanks

Comment: If you expect a good quality answer, provide some minimal code example of your efforts so far. The primary purpose of this website is to provide answers to specific coding issues.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found out that the S3Uploader class used by the s3_direct_upload gem has the same methods as the jQuery-File-Upload from which it is derived.

So one can call $("#s3_uploader").fileupload('send', {files: [f]});

And the f File will be uploaded to S3 directly